# salvar numeros aleatorios

Tags: php

estou fazendo um site de gerar cupons promocionais, porem na hora de salvar no banco de dados está dando esse erro. Notice: Array to string conversion in. gostaria de saber se alguem consegue me ajudar. segue o codigo abaixo:

// vem do formulario

```
$preco = $_POST['preco'];
$promo = $_POST['promo'];


// conta
    $resultado = $preco / $promo;
```

// gera o numero aleatorio ]

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $resultado; $i++) { $n[] = str_pad(rand(10000000, 99999999), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); }


sort($n);

echo implode('<br/>', $n);
```

function cadastracaixa($conexao, $preco, $promo, $n){

```
  $inserir = "insert into cupons (preco, promo, cupons) values ({$preco}, {$promo}, '{$n}')";

  $resultadoDaInsercao = mysqli_query($conexao, $inserir);
  return $resultadoDaInsercao;
```

}

if(cadastracaixa($conexao, $preco, $promo, $n)){
echo  "alert('dados inseridos com sucesso');";
}else{
$msg = mysqli_error($conexao);
echo  "alert('dados nao inseridos. Tente novamente');";
}

Comment: $n[] é um array, você precisa convertê-lo a string.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você poderia usar:

```
$n = str_pad(rand(10000000, 99999999), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Já que o **str_pad** retorna uma string.

Se a coluna da tabela for uma varchar ou um int e você está passando o $n[] vai dar problema por ser um array

Answer (score 0):

a sua variavel $n é um array, voce teria que pegar a posicao $n[x] ou usar a coluna do tipo JSON e guardar o array com JSON_ARRAY($n)